# Deedle - what is most efficient (fastest) way to replace an item in a column based on value of another item in another column on the same row

Tags: f#, deedle

I have this data frame

```
     AutoStat_1 AutoStat_2 Mode_1 Mode_2 Setpoint_1 Setpoint_2 
0 -> 0          0          1      1      23         24
1 -> 0          1          1      0      23         27
2 -> 1          1          3      0      26         27         
3 -> 1          0          3      1      26         24
4 -> 0          0          1      2      24         24
5 -> 0          0          1      2      24         24
6 -> 2          3          0      4      24         26
7 -> 2          3          0      4      25         26
```

The requirement is that if `AutoStat_i` is `not 0` then `Mode_i` and `Setpoint_i` will be the value of the above (in-front) of which `AutoStat_i` is `0`

The result should be (notice the column `Setpoint_i` and `Mode_i` are different than above)

```
     AutoStat_1 AutoStat_2 Mode_1 Mode_2 Setpoint_1 Setpoint_2
0 -> 0          0          1      1      23         24
1 -> 0          1          1      1      23         24
2 -> 1          1          1      1      23         24
3 -> 1          0          1      1      23         24
4 -> 0          0          1      2      24         24
5 -> 0          0          1      2      24         24
6 -> 2          3          1      2      24         24
7 -> 2          3          1      2      24         24
```

What've I tried:
My idea is for each set `i` of `(AutoStat_i, Mode_i, Setpoint_i)`, scan each row if `AutoStat_i` is `<> 0` then set the other values to `NaN`, after that I will just do the `fillMissing` with `Direction.Forward`. Below is the impementation

```
let calculateNonSFi (df:Frame<_,string>) idx = 
    let autoStatusName = sprintf "AutoStat_%d" idx
    let setpointName   = sprintf "Setpoint_%d" idx
    let modeName       = sprintf "Mode_%d" idx
    let setMissingOnMode (s:ObjectSeries<string>) =
        let s2 = s.As<float>()
        if s2.[autoStatusName] <> 0. then
            Series.replaceArray [|setpointName;modeName|] Double.NaN s2
        else
            s2
    df.Rows
    |> Series.mapValues setMissingOnMode
    |> Frame.ofRows
    |> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Forward
    |> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Backward

// for each set i do the folding
[0..150]
|> List.fold calculateNonSFi df
```

It gave me the expected results, however, for 150sets of 8000rows, it took more than 30 minutes to complete. I kinda see where it's wrong as for every set it acts on the whole dataset but I cannot think of a better way.

The logic is quite simple. I believe there should be a better way, do advice, thanks.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for reproduction

```
open Deedle
open System
let df = 
    [
        {| AutoStat_1=0;Setpoint_1=23;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=0;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=1|}
        {| AutoStat_1=0;Setpoint_1=23;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=1;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=1|}
        {| AutoStat_1=1;Setpoint_1=23;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=1;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=1|}
        {| AutoStat_1=1;Setpoint_1=23;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=0;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=1|}
        {| AutoStat_1=0;Setpoint_1=24;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=0;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=2|}
        {| AutoStat_1=0;Setpoint_1=24;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=0;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=2|}
        {| AutoStat_1=2;Setpoint_1=24;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=3;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=2|}
        {| AutoStat_1=2;Setpoint_1=24;Mode_1=1;AutoStat_2=3;Setpoint_2=24;Mode_2=2|}
    ] |> Frame.ofRecords
df.Print()

let calculateNonSFi (df:Frame<_,string>) idx = 
    let autoStatusName = sprintf "AutoStat_%d" idx
    let setpointName   = sprintf "Setpoint_%d" idx
    let modeName       = sprintf "Mode_%d" idx
    let setMissingOnMode (s:ObjectSeries<string>) =
        let s2 = s.As<float>()
        if s2.[autoStatusName] <> 0. then
            Series.replaceArray [|setpointName;modeName|] Double.NaN s2
        else
            s2
    df.Rows
    |> Series.mapValues setMissingOnMode
    |> Frame.ofRows
    |> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Forward

let df1 = 
    [1..2]
    |> List.fold calculateNonSFi df
df1.Print()
```

Advice/Answer from Tomas

```
df
|> Frame.mapRows (fun _ o -> 
  [ for i in 0 .. 150 do
      let au = o.GetAs<float>("AutoStat_" + string i)
      yield "AutoStat_" + string i, au
      yield "Mode_" + string i, if au <> 0. then nan else o.GetAs("Mode_" + string i)
      yield "Setpoint_" + string i, if au <> 0. then nan else o.GetAs("Setpoint_" + string i) ]
  |> series )
|> Frame.ofRows
|> Frame.fillMissing Direction.Forward
```

which yields correct result but in different column order hence my mistake in the earlier edit

```
     AutoStat_1 Mode_1 Setpoint_1 AutoStat_2 Mode_2 Setpoint_2 
0 -> 0          1      23         0          1      24
1 -> 0          1      23         1          1      24
2 -> 1          1      23         1          1      24         
3 -> 1          1      23         0          1      24
4 -> 0          1      24         0          2      24
5 -> 0          1      24         0          2      24
6 -> 2          1      24         3          2      24
7 -> 2          1      24         3          2      24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think your strategy of setting `Mode_i` and `Setpoint_i` to `NA` when `AutoStat_i` is not `0` and then filling the missing values is a nice approach.

You can certainly make it a bit faster by moving the `fillMissing` call outside of the `calculateNonSFi` function - the `fillMissing` operation will run on the whole frame, so you need to run this once at the end.

The second thing would be to find a way of setting the `NA` values that only iterates over the frame once. One option (I have not tested this) would be to use `Frame.mapRows` and, inside the function, iterate over all the columns (rather than iterating over all the columns and calling `mapRows` repeatedly). Something like:

```
df
|> Frame.mapRows (fun _ o -> 
  [ for i in 0 .. 150 do
      let au = o.GetAs<float>("AutoStat_" + string i)
      yield "AutoStat_" + string i, au
      yield "Mode_" + string i, if au = 0. then nan else o.GetAs("Mode_" + string i)
      yield "Setpoint_" + string i, if au = 0. then nan else o.GetAs("Setpoint_" + string i) ]
  |> series )
|> Frame.ofRows
```

Comment: hi Tomas, thanks for the advice, I tried your code and it works (the condition should be ```au<>0.``` though). The column order of the result is different than my result so initially I thought it's wrong, apologize. However, in the ```df``` there are other unrelated columns that I need for the next step, not sure how to keep them, should I slice them off and join them back together. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I was also thinking that all the ```set_i``` are independent and I may parallelize the process using async, but I have an issue of joining them as they have the same columns name and there is no replaceCols that I'm aware of

Comment: @JoseVu Yes, you should be able to slice & merge the remaining columns - that sounds like a good strategy to me.